# Keep k8s secrets in github actions

Tags: json, go, github, kubernetes, github-actions

We are trying to use `github actions`, and we want to keep sensitive data such as `kubeconfig` inside the github `secrets`
I've created a GitHub secret with name `KUBECONFIG1`

**Steps to reproduce**

In the GitHub secret I should store the following file also tried to convert to JSON with this https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
  - name: brf
    cluster:
      certificate-authority-data: >-
        LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURTakNBd0t6RXBNQ2NHQTFVRUF4TWdkbWx5ZE2bUljTlRtakFWCi0tLS0tRU5EIENFUlRJRklDQVRFLS0tLS0=
      server: 'https://vfg.canary.k8s.ondemand.com'
users:
  - name: user1
    user:
      token: >-
        eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuW1lc3BhY2UiOiJnYXJkZW4tZGV2e
contexts:
  - name: g-root
    context:
      cluster: garv
      user: robot
      namespace: gking
current-context: gaot
```

in the github actions workflow we keep the file content above with the name `KUBECONFIG1` and create from it k8s secret.

```
name: Example action

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install k8s
        run: |
          curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=777 sh -
          cat /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
          mkdir -p ~/.kube
          cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config


     - run: 'echo -e "$KUBECONFIG1" > ~/.tmpfile.json'
        shell: bash
        env:
          KUBECONFIG1: ${{secrets.KUBECONFIG1}}
    
      - name: example 
        shell: bash
        run: |
          cd ~/
          kubectl create secret generic project-kubecfg --from-file=~/.tmpfile.json -n default
```

After running this workflow I got the following error:

```
error: error loading config file "/home/runner/work/_temp/kubeconfig_1617030542039": couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct *** APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" ***
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I try also to take the file content and use
https://onlinelinuxtools.com/escape-shell-characters

As we work with Golang maybe I should take the kubeconfig and use it as go template and save the `sensitive-data` like `token` `certificate-authority-data` etc as github secret and during the workflow update the secrets value to the template but not sure how...

**What I need at the end** I need that the following command will work in the workflow

`kubectl create secret generic project-kubecfg --from-file=~/.tmpfile.json -n default`

Comment: Can you show the value of `KUBECONFIG1` with tokens redacted?

Comment: @jordanm - I see asterisks when I do `cat .tmpfile.json`

Comment: @jordanm - the file is valid as I double check it locally, I mean take the same content which I put in the value of the github secret and create a k8s secret with it using `kubectl create secret generic ...`

Comment: In your action, `cat` the file before `kubectl create` to see if it still contains what you think it does.

Comment: I have a similar problem requiring credentials (to e.g. connect to databases) to be held in encrypted form and then decrypted on the fly. That way the encypted yaml file (although it would work with JSON) can be pushed and treated like any other text file. For use with Go I use the Argon libraries https://github.com/SnowyUK/argon. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the below command

```yaml
kubectl create secret generic project-kubecfg --from-file=~/.tmpfile.json -n default
```

The problem is that `~` goes to `kubectl` which doesn't expand it to the home directory. So if you change it like below it will work

```yaml
kubectl create secret generic project-kubecfg --from-file=/home/runner/.tmpfile.json -n default
```

Or rather use a fixed path instead of home directory with `~`